# Can you use code for a specific font and font color with pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

Very amateur python programmer here with a question about pytesseract.  I'm using pytesseract to scan work orders at work, but it's not doing a very good job.

Often the words that appear on the work order are in different fonts, and are different colors with different colored backgrounds. Fortunately, the only info I need pytesseract to read on this documents is always in black Ariel font on a white background.  Is there any way to program pytesseract to only look for specific fonts and font colors, and if there is would that potentially make the pytesseract read cleaner?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)